# How to find fare information for Dublin Buses?

Tags: buses, fares, dublin

I will be going to Dublin in a few days, but I can't find what are the prices for a given bus ride in Dublin when using Dublin Bus specifically

[DublinBus](https://www.dublinbus.ie/Fares-and-Tickets/Adult/) states :

|  | Leap | Cash |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Short Zone | €1.30● | €1.70 |
| Long Zone | €2.00● | €2.60 |
| Xpresso | €2.40● | €3.00 |

But I'm having trouble figuring which routes are counted in each fare category.

Looking about the route `41` starting from the Airport, I would assume that such route would be priced as an `Long Zone` route, but I am not sure.

I will be ordering a Leap Card, so that is more to gauge how much to top-up on order.

Comment: [This page](https://about.leapcard.ie/bus-eireann-in-dublin-area) shows the bus zones.

Comment: If you're trying to get from the airport to the city center, the [Aircoach](https://dodublin.ie/airport-transfers/aircoach/ticket-options) is much faster and more frequent.  It is more expensive at EUR 7.00, though, and I believe you get tickets on your phone instead of using a Leap card.

Comment: @WeatherVane: That map is for multi-ride commuter tickets, and it doesn't seem to correlate with the short/long options for single rides.

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, I have looked that up, but sadly doesn't match with the flights I am taking

Comment: It looks like the AirCoach runs from 05:55 to 01:25.  You're really arriving in the "wee hours"?

Comment: And from city to airport, there is a departure at 02:24, then half-hourly from 03:24 onward, for those very early morning flights.  Your flights must be at some extremely odd hours?

Comment: I can't see a service later than 23:55 which would likely be too tight, I haven't tried (my bad) to check the following day (thinking that it would show them logically). 00:25 is fine, I will likely go with that.

Comment: Yeah, if you look at the next day, I think you'll see 0:25, 0:55, 1:25.  (I guess they're not actually more frequent though; the #41 also has departures every 30 minutes.  I misread its timetable before.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the Dublin Bus page on the [TFI Leap Card site](https://about.leapcard.ie/dublin-bus) that states that a `Long Zone` trip is a trip more than ~3km in length :

> For short single journeys tell the driver your destination and hold your TFI Leap Card to the target on the driver’s ticket machine. The correct fare will be deducted for your journey.

> For journeys over 3km / involving transfer / Nitelink use the Validator on the right hand side as you enter the bus. The appropriate fare will be deducted from your Travel Credit